# Enter Captcha before Contact Form Submission PHP & Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms, captcha

I have a contact form for users to contact me if they need help with something. The thing is I can't get the captcha to work.

contact_form.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Contact Form</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="" /> 
<meta name="description" content="" /> 
<link href="tooplate_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script  src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="tooplate_wrapper">

    <div id="tooplate_header">

        <div id="site_title"><h1><a href="http://deathsrepo.pw">Technologx</a></h1></div>         
        <div id="twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/Technologx" target="_blank"></a></div>

        <div id="facebook"><a href="https://facebook.com/Technologx2013" target="_blank"></a></div>

        <div id="tooplate_menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://deathsrepo.pw/themes.php">Themes</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://blog.deathsrepo.pw">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://deathsrepo.pw/store.php">Store</a></li>
                <li class="last"></li>
                <li><a href="http://deathsrepo.pw/contact_form.php" class="current">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li class="last"></li>
            </ul>       
        </div> <!-- end of tooplate_menu -->
<style>


body, div, h1,h2, form, fieldset, input, textarea, footer,p {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: none;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'YanoneKaffeesatzRegular';
    src: url('fonts/yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.svg#YanoneKaffeesatzRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body { font-family: 'YanoneKaffeesatzRegular';}
p {text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff; font-size:24px;}
#wrap {width:530px; margin:20px auto 0; height:1000px;}
h1 {margin-bottom:20px; text-align:center;font-size:48px; text-shadow:0 1px 0 #ede8d9; }


    #form_wrap { overflow:hidden; height:446px; position:relative; top:0px;
        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out .3s;
        -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out .3s;
        -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out .3s;
        transition: all 1s ease-in-out .3s;}

    #form_wrap:before {content:"";
        position:absolute;
        bottom:128px;left:0px;
        background:url('images/before.png');
        width:530px;height: 316px;}

    #form_wrap:after {content:"";position:absolute;
        bottom:0px;left:0;
        background:url('images/after.png');
        width:530px;height: 260px; }

    #form_wrap.hide:after, #form_wrap.hide:before {display:none; }
    #form_wrap:hover {height:776px;top:-200px;}


    form {background:#f7f2ec url('images/letter_bg.png'); 
        position:relative;top:200px;overflow:hidden;
        height:200px;width:400px;margin:0px auto;padding:20px; 
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 3px; 
        -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #9d9d9d, inset 0px 0px 27px #fff;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #9d9d9d, inset 0px 0px 14px #fff;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #9d9d9d, inset 0px 0px 27px #fff;
        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out .3s;
        -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out .3s;
        -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out .3s;
        transition: all 1s ease-in-out .3s;}


        #form_wrap:hover form {height:530px;}

        label {
            margin: 11px 20px 0 0; 
            font-size: 16px; color: #b3aba1;
            text-transform: uppercase; 
            text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
        }

        input[type=text], textarea {
            font: 14px normal normal uppercase helvetica, arial, serif;
            color: #7c7873;background:none;
            width: 380px; height: 36px; padding: 0px 10px; margin: 0 0 10px 0;
            border:1px solid #f8f5f1;
            -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px;
            -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px #726959;
            -webkit-box-shadow:  inset 0px 0px 1px #b3a895; 
            box-shadow:  inset 0px 0px 1px #b3a895;
        }   

        textarea { height: 80px; padding-top:14px;}

        textarea:focus, input[type=text]:focus {background:rgba(255,255,255,.35);}

        #form_wrap input[type=submit] {
            position:relative;font-family: 'YanoneKaffeesatzRegular'; 
            font-size:24px; color: #7c7873;text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;
            width:100%; text-align:center;opacity:0;
            background:none;
            cursor: pointer;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; 
            -webkit-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out 0s;
            -moz-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out 0s;
            -o-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out 0s;
            transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out 0s;
        }

        #form_wrap:hover input[type=submit] {z-index:1;opacity:1;
            -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out 1.3s;
            -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out 1.3s;
            -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out 1.3s;
            transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out 1.3s;}

            #form_wrap:hover input:hover[type=submit] {color:#435c70;}

</style>
<body><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <div id="wrap">
        <h1>Contact Form</h1>
        <div id='form_wrap'>
            <form method="post" action="php/send.php" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);>
                <p>Hello Guest,</p>
                <label for="email">Your Message : </label>
                <textarea  name="message" value="Your Message" id="message" ></textarea>    
                <label for="name">Name: </label>
                <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" />
                <label for="email">Email: </label>
                <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" />            
<img src="php/captcha.php" width="120" height="50" border="1" alt="CAPTCHA">
<input type="text" size="6" maxlength="5" name="captcha" value="" />
                <input type="submit" name ="submit" value="Send"/>
            </form>
                    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function checkForm(form) { if(!form.captcha.value.match(/^\d{5}$/)) { alert('Please enter the CAPTCHA digits in the box provided'); form.captcha.focus(); return false; } return true; } </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

captcha.php:

```
<?PHP
$image = @imagecreatetruecolor(160, 45) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background = imagecolorallocate($image, 0x66, 0xCC, 0xFF); 
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $background); 
$linecolor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0x33, 0x99, 0xCC); 
$textcolor1 = imagecolorallocate($image, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00); 
$textcolor2 = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
for($i=0; $i < 8; $i++) { imagesetthickness($image, rand(1,3)); imageline($image, rand(0,160), 0, rand(0,160), 45, $linecolor); } 

session_start();
$fonts = array(); 
$fonts[] = "../fonts/Courier New.ttf"; 
$fonts[] = "../fonts/Courier New Italic.ttf"; 
$fonts[] = "../fonts/Courier New Bold.ttf";
$digit = ''; for($x = 10; $x <= 130; $x += 30) { $textcolor = (rand() % 2) ? $textcolor1 : $textcolor2; $digit .= ($num = rand(0, 9)); imagettftext($image, 20, rand(-30,30), $x, rand(20, 42), 
$textcolor, $fonts[array_rand($fonts)], $num); }
 $_SESSION['digit'] = $digit;
 header('Content-type: image/png'); 
 imagepng($image); imagedestroy($image);
 ?>
```

I want the captcha part to work because in the past when I had a contact forum I had people sending me nothing but nonsense that had nothing to do with the question they were being asked. This is to also stop spam bots. If you guy's would like to look at the live version to see what's going on you can do so [here](http://test.deathsrepo.pw/contact_form.php). All that's happening is I can enter information and press submit without even entering the captcha.

Comment: your description of the problem is *lacking*

Comment: What do you mean it's lacking?

Comment: "I can't get the captcha to work" tells us absolutely nothing

Comment: I added more below the captcha.php code

Comment: So can you help me out?

Comment: Have you tried other solutions such as Google's Recapcha? Its easy to install? http://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/

Comment: I couldn't quit figure it out and it's to big for my letter & envelope animation.

Comment: Verify captcha after submitting the form and not before.

Comment: I want it verified before submission

Answer (score 0):

OPTION 1 (JSON)

send.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (!empty($_POST['contact'])) {
    $errors = array();
    // verify form
    if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors[] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
    }
    // ... etc..

    if (empty($_POST['captcha']) || $_SESSION['digit'] != $_POST['captcha']) {
        $errors[] = "Invalid Verification Code.";
    }
    if (!empty($errors)) {
        $errorStr = "The current request did not complete successfully...\n\n";
        $errorStr .= "- " . implode("\n- ", $errors);

        $res_arr = array('statusNum' => 2, 'message' => $errorStr);
        echo json_encode($res_arr);
    } else {
        // send email
        $res_arr = array('statusNum' => 1, 'message' => "Thank you!");
        echo json_encode($res_arr);
    }
    exit;
}
?>
```

contact_form.php

```
<form method="post" action="php/send.php" id="contactForm">
  <p>Hello Guest,</p>
  <label for="message">Your Message:</label>
  <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" />
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" />
  <img src="php/captcha.php" width="120" height="50" border="1" alt="CAPTCHA" id="captcha_image">
  <input type="text" size="6" maxlength="5" name="captcha" value="" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" id="submitbutton" />
  <input type="reset" name="reset" id="resetbutton" value="Reset" style="visibility: hidden;" />
  <input type="hidden" name="contact" value="1" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var inProcess_contact = 0;
$('#contactForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (inProcess_contact == 0) {
        inProcess_contact = 1;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            url: $('form#contactForm').attr('action'),
            data: $('form#contactForm').serialize(),
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#contactForm #submitbutton').val('Please wait...');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#contactForm #submitbutton').val('Send');
                if (data.statusNum == 1) {
                    $('#contactForm #resetbutton').click();
                }
                inProcess_contact = 0;
                var d = new Date();
                $("#captcha_image").attr("src", "php/captcha.php?"+d.getTime());
                alert(data.message);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#contactForm #submitbutton').val('Send');
                inProcess_contact = 0;
                var d = new Date();
                $("#captcha_image").attr("src", "php/captcha.php?"+d.getTime());
                alert(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

---

OPTION 2 (HTML)

send.php

```
<?php 
// never forget to start the session
session_start();

$errors = "";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  if(empty($_SESSION['6_letters_code'] ) ||
    strcasecmp($_SESSION['6_letters_code'], $_POST['6_letters_code']) != 0)
  {
      //Note: the captcha code is compared case insensitively.
      //if you want case sensitive match, update the check above to
      // strcmp()
    $errors .= "n The captcha code does not match!";
  }

  if(empty($errors))
  {
    //send the email
    $to = $your_email;
    $subject="Help Needed";
    $from = $your_email;
    $ip = isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : '';

    $body = "A user  $name submitted the contact form: \n".
    "Name: $name \n".
    "Email: $email \n".
    "Message: $message \n".
    "$user_message \n";

    $headers = "From: $from rn";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email rn";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
        echo "ok";
    } else {
        echo "Coudn't send email. Please try again.";
    }
    //header('Location: submitted.php');
  } else {
      echo $errors;
  }
  exit;
}
?>
```

contact_form.php

```
<div id="result"></div>
<form method="post" action="php/send.php" id="contactForm">
  <p>Hello Guest,</p>
  <label for="message">Your Message:</label>
  <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" />
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" />
  <img src="php/captcha.php" width="120" height="50" border="1" alt="CAPTCHA" id="captcha_image">
  <input type="text" size="6" maxlength="5" name="6_letters_code" value="" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" id="submitbutton" />
  <input type="reset" name="reset" id="resetbutton" value="Reset" style="visibility: hidden;" />
  <input type="hidden" name="contact" value="1" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var inProcess_contact = 0;
$('#contactForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (inProcess_contact == 0) {
        inProcess_contact = 1;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "html",
            url: $('form#contactForm').attr('action'),
            data: $('form#contactForm').serialize(),
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#contactForm #submitbutton').val('Please wait...');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == 'ok') {
                    $('#contactForm #resetbutton').click();
                    $("#result").html('Request Succeeded');
                    // redirect after 3 seconds
                    setTimeout(function() {window.location = 'submitted.php';}, 3000);
                } else {
                    inProcess_contact = 0;
                    $('#contactForm #submitbutton').val('Send');
                    var d = new Date();
                    $("#captcha_image").attr("src", "php/captcha.php?"+d.getTime());
                    //alert(data.message);
                    $("#result").html(data);
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#contactForm #submitbutton').val('Send');
                inProcess_contact = 0;
                var d = new Date();
                $("#captcha_image").attr("src", "php/captcha.php?"+d.getTime());
                //alert(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
                $("#result").html(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is what my send.php consists of: [send.php](https://ghostbin.com/paste/fxcmb)

Comment: parsererror: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: i dont understand what's the point of the extra code (css style, javascript timer) in your send.php file?